# Typescript Error Cannot find name 'FirebaseService'. - Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I've tried to install a new Ionic plugin (cordova-plugin-device, which I already had) and now I can't serve or build my App. This is the error I get when I try to serve it. I haven't changed anything, tried to update Node/Ionic/NPM packages, but still, nothing helps at all.

`Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'FirebaseService'.
node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts`

This is my Ionic Info:

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.12 
Node       : v8.9.3
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to roll back to firebase 4.8.0

```
npm uninstall --save firebase
npm install --save firebase@4.8.0
```

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387
- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/234
- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/525